# How do I set a TXSDateTime in a soap application

Tags: delphi

I am building an application that MUST use soap for all database requirements.

I used the WSSL Importer in Delphi 10.2 to create the classes required.

The WSDL Importer sets fields of type Datetime to

createdDate: TXSDateTime;

My program collects date in a TDateTime

When I try to set createddate using

```
myCl.createdDate := adatetimevariable
```

The compiler throws the error:

```
E2010 Incompatible types: 'TXSDateTime' and 'TDateTime'
```

How can I set a TXSDatetim Variable.

Comment: the documentation states that to convert to TDatetime use AsDateTime http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Soap.XSBuiltIns.TXSDateTime

Comment: @John Easley - That is what the documentation says to convert TXSDateTime -> TDateTime. But I am going the other way. TDateTime -> TXSDateTime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it.

When Delphi gets the response to the date if a Date fiel in empty then the corresponding Date variable in the class is set to nil.

To assign a value to it I have to first check if it is **nil** and then create it. And use asDateTime to set it.

```
if myCl.createdDate = nil then
  mcCl.createdDate := TXSDatetime.Create;
myCl.createdDate.AsDateTime := adatetimevariable;
```

Thanks to John Easley for the pointer to AsDateTime which I revisited to figure this out.